# Why do these two different ways to access a member of a struct-within-a-struct work?

Tags: c, struct

I don't understand how, the code below, `homeroom.roster[0].lastname` and `(*homeroom.roster).lastname` are the reference. When the code is run, both printf calls print out "Jones"

Specifically, I get that `roster[0]` and `roster` are the same address from how arrays work in C, but how are `homeroom.roster[0].lastname` and `(*homeroom.roster).lastname` equivalent? The asterisk is throwing me for a loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    char firstname[22];
    char lastname[22];
} Student;

typedef struct {
    int size;
    Student roster[33];
} Class;

void main() {

  Class homeroom;
  strcpy(homeroom.roster[0].lastname,"Jones");
  printf("%s\n",homeroom.roster[0].lastname);
  printf("%s\n",(*homeroom.roster).lastname);
  
}
```

There's no pointer, and yet an asterisk works...how? Why?

Comment: `pointer[i]` is equivalent to `*(pointer+i)` so when `i == 0` it's the same as `*pointer`.

Comment: And it doesn't have to be a real pointer. An array decays to a pointer to its first element in this context. So `*array` is the same as `array[0]`

Comment: And, in fact, for any `x` that you can put  a `*` in front of or a `[…]` after, `*x` is the same as `x[0]`.